# How can I do a background search and post the results without saving them in Rails 4?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, polling

I'll try to keep my question simple. Basically I've got two models in a HMABTM (has many and belongs to many) relation. What I'd like to do is let user find records meeting the criteria (the output would be probably a few records from the second model).

**The problem I'm facing:**

The database is quite big (~800 mil records), the amount of requests/queries at the same time is not so big though. Still saving the search results is not an optimal solution for me, so I would like the results to be displayed via jquery (or js in general) from a running background job and NOT saved in the database.

**What I thought of:**

Using `sidekiq`, though I'm not really familiar with background jobs in rails. I just don't understand how I would possibly ask for results. Some people pointed out using Ajax would be the best idea here, but is being stuck with such a task running on Ajax a good idea, and would it even work?

Answer (score 0):

Better way to use `ajax` requests. With `jQuery` it will be like that:

```
function getData( value ) {
    $.ajax( {  
        url: "/path_to/your_action",  
        data: {  
            variable: value  
        },  
        dataType: "json",
        complete: function( data ) {  
            // process your data  
        }  
    } );  
}
```

And process request in `Rails`:

```
def your_action  
    render :json => ModelName.where( :column_name => params[ :variable ] )  
end
```

If your table have good indexes then it will be fast.